# Getting list of files

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a directory named 'import' and would like to get all files and their corresponding date (based on filename). Sample content of the directory is this:

- input_02202010.xls
- input_02212010.xls
- input_02222010.xls

I would like to have a Map that contains the path of the file and a Date variable.

Can anyone show me how Groovy will solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use `new File("/foo/bar/import").list()` to get the file names, just like you would in Java. Then create file objects from the strings and check lastModified() for the last modification date.

EDIT:
Groovy adds `eachFile()` methods to java.io.File, we can use that to make it a bit more groovy...

To extract the date from the filename, use

```
Date d = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy").parse(filename.substring(6,14))
```

To make it all into a map (using the filename as key and the date as value, though redundant):

```
def df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy")
def results = [:]
new File("/foo/bar/import").eachFile() { file -> 
   results.put(file.getName(), df.parse(file.getName().substring(6,14)))
}

results
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. would like to know how to extract the date string from the filename using Groovy - Regex: 
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions

i.e. input_02202010.xls -> 02202010

Comment: def s = "input_02222010.xls"
def s2 = s =~ /input_([\d]+)\.xls/
assert "02222010" == s2[0][1]